# Session store per Rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session-cookies

How can we setup a Rails engine to have it's own `session_store` configuration?

So far we have tried the following:

`Console::Engine.config.session_store :active_record_store, key: '_session_id'`

Which outputs the following error:

```
/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `session_store' for #<Rails::Engine::Configuration:0x00007fb6859ba238> (NoMethodError)
    from /Code/App/engines/console/config/initializers/session_store.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
```

The reason is that Rails::Engine::Configuration does not have `session_store` but `Rails::Application::Configuration` does.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: An engine has to run within the context of an application, so this is unlikely to work.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @dbugger currently the `_session_id` can be copied from the browser console, then the user can visit any of our subdomains and change the `_session_id` which bypass the normal login process. It's a security issue.

Comment: Not sure what approach to take in order to prevent this to happen.

Comment: Are you not using devise or an other auth gem?  If you are doing a multi-tenant app you might want to look at the apartment gem.  This sounds like a more fundamental problem with your authentication strategy/implementation.